# Converting Dictionary Values to new Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am pulling json data from an API and have a number of columns in my dataframe that contain dictionaries. These dictionaries are written so that the id and the value are two separate entries in the dictionary like so:

```
{'id': 'AnnualUsage', 'value': '13071'}
```

Some of the rows for these columns contain only one dictionary entry like shown above, but others can contain up to 7:

```
[{'id': 'AnnualUsage', 'value': '13071'},
 {'id': 'TestId', 'value': 'Z13753'},
 {'id': 'NumberOfMe', 'value': '3'},
 {'id': 'Prem', 'value': '960002'},
 {'id': 'ProjectID', 'value': '0039'},
 {'id': 'Region', 'value': 'CHR'},
 {'id': 'Tariff', 'value': 'Multiple'},
 {'id': 'Number', 'value': '06860702'}]
```

When I attempt to break this dictionary down into separate column attributes

```
CTG_df2 = pd.concat([CTG_df['id'], CTG_df['applicationUDFs'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

I end up with columns in a dataframe each containing a dictionary of the above entry i.e.

```
{'id': 'AnnualUsageDE', 'value': '13071'}
```

Is there a way for me to convert my dictionary values into new key-value pairs? For instance I would like to convert from:

```
{'id': 'AnnualUsageDE', 'value': '13071'}
```

to

```
{'AnnualUsageDE': '13071'}
```

If this is possible I will then be able to create new columns from these attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a dict comprehension. From your list of dicts, compose a new dict where the key is the `id` of each element and the value is the `value` of each element.

```
original = [{'id': 'AnnualUsage', 'value': '13071'},
            {'id': 'TestId', 'value': 'Z13753'},
            {'id': 'NumberOfMe', 'value': '3'},
            {'id': 'Prem', 'value': '960002'},
            {'id': 'ProjectID', 'value': '0039'},
            {'id': 'Region', 'value': 'CHR'},
            {'id': 'Tariff', 'value': 'Multiple'},
            {'id': 'Number', 'value': '06860702'}]

newdict = {subdict['id']: subdict['value'] for subdict in original}
print(newdict)
# {'AnnualUsage': '13071',
#  'Number': '06860702',
#  'NumberOfMe': '3',
#  'Prem': '960002',
#  'ProjectID': '0039',
#  'Region': 'CHR',
#  'Tariff': 'Multiple',
#  'TestId': 'Z13753'}
```

Comment: Elegant answer!

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the exact solution I am looking for. I am wondering if you would know how to iterate it through a column of a dataframe though. So if each row in the column has its own 'original' dictionary, how can I apply the 'newdict' dict comprehension to it? I tried something along the lines of ```CTG_df2['new'] = {subdict['id']: subdict['value'] for subdict in CTG_df2.iloc[0,]}``` but it does not seem to iterate correctly

Comment: It looks like my best bet currently is to use a while loop and iterate through each row as such ```i=0
while i < 100:
    a = CTG_df['applicationUDFs'][i]
    CTG_df['applicationUDFs'][i] = {subdict['id']: subdict['value'] for subdict in a}
    i = i + 1``` but if there is a cleaner way to do this I would be interested in finding out.

Comment: @DaveWilson Given your `original`, you can do `pandas.DataFrame(original)` which will split the original dict into separate columns for keys and values; if this isn't what you want, might be more useful to edit your question or make a new one in order to specifically say you want a pandas solution - I'm not very experienced with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the values and set each of them to the dictionary value:

```
newdict = dict()
for x in original:
    newdict[x["id"]] = x["value"]
```